# WPF: Creating a Binding.ValidationRule without Binding to a property

Tags: .net, wpf, validation, c#-4.0

I am trying to add validation to one of my WPF controls that does not have a binding to anything. I researched a bit and found out that to do this, it suffices to bind the control to itself.

Unfortunately, VS is giving me a cryptic error message on this piece of code:

```
<TextBox  x:Name="_manualTextBox"  MinWidth="200" Margin="20,0,5,2" TextChanged="_manualTextBox_TextChanged">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Text" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <val:ServerNameValidation ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Where the error message occurs on the line:

`<val:ServerNameValidation ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>`

And it claims:

```
A value of type 'ServerNameValidation' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'Collection1'.
```

My ServerNameValidation class inherits from ValidationRule and implements the Validate method:

```
public class ServerNameValidation : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
```

The xmlns seems to be correctly configured as the Intellisense in VS will catch my ServerNameValidation and my `ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: see whether this helps you http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/56554ba7-a03b-4f87-a197-5050b1c339fc/wpf-textbox-validation

Comment: I believe my code is doing what this article speaks of already.